# The eigenspace of $\lambda$ is simply the null space of the matrix $A-\lambda I$. Is that correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Would it be correct to say that the eigenspace corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$ for a matrix $A$ is simply the null space of the matrix $A-\lambda I$? My justification is that the eigenspace is made up of every vector $x$ such that $Ax - \lambda I=0$, but if $x$ satsifies that equation then it is in the null space of $A-\lambda I$.

Is there a difference between the two that I'm missing? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

By definition, the eigenspace is the space of all vectors $v$ satisfying $Av=\lambda v$. This is equivalent to $Av-\lambda v=0$ or $(A-\lambda I)v=0$. So the eigenspace of $\lambda$ is equal to the nullspace of $A-\lambda I$, as you stated.

Comment: Got it, thank you!